# Three.JS r71: Transparent renderer doesn't work with post-processing filters

Tags: javascript, three.js, rendering, webgl

I'm trying to render a BloomPass on my current scene, and have the background show through from the body of the containing page. However, when the BloomPass is applied, the background becomes black.

`My example is here:`http://plnkr.co/edit/0mp0jaGVF6it52HY7aq2?p=preview

I tried following the suggestions in this quite old thread here https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1080 on my local version of the plunkr (e.g Changing the ClearAlpha flags in RenderPass), but these have no effect. This black background also persists regardless of which shaders I use (Tried also with FilmPass and FXAA)

Running Chrome 45.0.2454.101 (64-bit) on Yosemite 10.10.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to use `EffectComposer` extensively, you will likely have to invest the time to understand it completely. There are a lot of subtleties.

You want the post-processing effect to be transparent.

To do so, you need to make sure the render targets used by the Composer have an alpha channel -- that is, are of `THREE.RGBAFormat`.

```
composer.renderTarget1.format = THREE.RGBAFormat;
composer.renderTarget2.format = THREE.RGBAFormat;
effectBloom.renderTargetX.format = THREE.RGBAFormat;
effectBloom.renderTargetY.format = THREE.RGBAFormat;
```

three.js r.73

Comment: Thank you WestLangley. This definitely fixed the problem, though I didn't see any documentation around these subtleties in any of the examples I explored. A lot more reading to be done.